# JasperReports Virtualizer not generating report even after 20 minutes

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We are generating *JR* report through web application.

My main report (landscape) includes 5 sub reports (landscape).

Till i include 4 subreports the report is getting generated both in *iReport* and from web application.

Moment we include 5th sub report the *iReport* fails to generate any report - the JVM throws `OutOfMemoryException`.

Then I went through forums/blogs/Ultimate guide and found out about *Virtualizer*.

I am using *FileVirtualizer* with size as 100.

My report contains data and lot of charts (out of 400 pages which will be generated for NOW, 200 pages contains charts. Data for which is being fetched from the DB.).

Using *FileVirtualizer* the JVM does not throw any exception but the report is not being generated. Lot of files are generated in the directory specified for *FileVirtualizer* however even after 30 mins the report is not getting generated. I counted close to 1,30,211 files in the directory mentioned for *FileVirtualizer* when the condition was just 2.

Using *FileSwap*, the process kept on going and going again with no output.

Using *GZip* with value 1024, the process kept on running, with no report.

Can anyone please guide what can be the possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing the margin. The sub report margin was bigger than main report margin and hence it went into infinite loop...A simple solution to an inherently complex problem...